# Lebesgue sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> A set $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is called $m^*$-measurable if for all $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$
> $$m^*(A)=m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A\cap E^c)$$

> The set of all measurable sets is called Lebesgue sigma algebra

Does not sigma algebra has properties? this is a way to "build" Lebesgue sigma algebra from "another way" by measurable sets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a $\sigma$-algebra has properties ! Let

$ \mathcal{L}= \{E \subseteq \mathbb R: m^*(A)=m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A\cap E^c) \quad \forall A \subseteq \mathbb R\}.$

$ \mathcal{L}$ has the following properties (try a proof):

1. $ \mathbb R \in  \mathcal{L}$;
2. $E\in  \mathcal{L}$ implies $\mathbb R \setminus E \in  \mathcal{L}$;
3. if $(E_j)$ is a  sequence in $ \mathcal{L}$, then $\bigcup E_j \in \mathcal{L}.$

This shows that $ \mathcal{L}$ is a $ \sigma$-algebra.

Comment: A sigma algebra is closed to any countable unions, not necessary disjoint.

Comment: So why did my lecture said that if Carathéodory criterion is met, it is a Lebesgue sigma algebra, is should be just a sigma algebra

Comment: Probably because they were just going to use the Lebesgue measure since this is the most common one in introductory integration and measure theory classes.

Comment: I agree with @NDewolf ... The "Lebesgue sigma-algebra" is the result of the OP definition in the case where $m^*$ is the Lebesgue outer measure.  For other outer measures, I may call it "$m^*$-measurable sets".