# If $\int_a^x f(t) \mathrm d t=0$ for all $x \in[a, b]$, then $f=0$ $\lambda$-a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[a, b]$. We endow $[a, b]$ with the [Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3117419/lebesgue-sigma-algebra) $\mathcal L([a, b])$. Then $([a, b], \mathcal L([a, b]), \lambda)$ is a [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure) measure space. I would like to see how Lebesgue integration fits in the framework of Bochner integration by proving below result, i.e.,

> **Theorem** Let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be [$\lambda$-integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space?noredirect=1&lq=1) such that
> $$
> \int_a^x f(t) \mathrm d t=0 \quad \text {for all } x \in[a, b].
> $$
> Then $f=0$ $\lambda$-a.e. on $[a, b]$.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

**Proof** It [suffices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4546113/bochner-integral-is-f-g-mu-a-e-if-their-integrals-are-equal-on-every-meas?rq=1) to prove that
$$
\int_A f(t) \mathrm d t = 0 \quad \forall A \in \mathcal L([a, b]).
$$

We have $\mathcal L([a, b])$ [is the completion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168953/completion-of-borel-sigma-algebra-with-respect-to-lebesgue-measure) of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B([a, b])$ of $[a, b]$ with respect to $\lambda$. So it suffices to prove that
$$
\int_A f(t) \mathrm d t = 0 \quad \forall A \in \mathcal B([a, b]).
$$

Let $\tau$ be the metric topology of $[a, b]$. Every set in $\tau$ [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318299/any-open-subset-of-bbb-r-is-a-countable-union-of-disjoint-open-intervals) a countable union of *disjoint* open intervals. Hence
$$
\int_O f(t) \mathrm d t = 0 \quad \forall O \in \tau.
$$

Fix $A \in \mathcal B([a, b])$. Because $\lambda$ [is outer regular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82023/a-question-about-regularity-of-borel-measures), there is a sequence $(O_n) \subset \tau$ such that $A \subset O_{n+1}\subset O_n$ and that $\lim_n \lambda(O_n) = \lambda(A)$. By dominated convergence theorem,
$$
\int_{A} f(t) \mathrm d t = \lim_n \int_{O_n} f(t) \mathrm d t = 0.
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: @Yanko Thank you so much for your verification!