# If $\int_a^x f(t) \mathrm d t=0$ for $\lambda$-a.e. $x \in[a, b]$, then $f=0$ $\lambda$-a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[a, b]$. We endow $[a, b]$ with the [Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3117419/lebesgue-sigma-algebra) $\mathcal L([a, b])$. Previously, I proved that

> [Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607770/if-int-ax-ft-mathrm-d-t-0-for-all-x-ina-b-then-f-0-lambda-a-e?noredirect=1#comment9709637_4607770) Let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be [$\lambda$-integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space?noredirect=1&lq=1) such that
> $$
> \int_a^x f(t) \mathrm d t=0 \quad \text {for all } x \in[a, b].
> $$
> Then $f=0$ $\lambda$-a.e. on $[a, b]$.

Now I would like to prove a natural generalization, i.e.,

> **Proposition** Let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be [$\lambda$-integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space?noredirect=1&lq=1) such that
> $$
> \int_a^x f(t) \mathrm d t=0 \quad \text{for } \lambda \text{-a.e. } x \in[a, b].
> $$
> Then $f=0$ $\lambda$-a.e. on $[a, b]$.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

**Proof** By the **Theorem**, it suffices to prove that $\int_a^x f(t) \mathrm d t=0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$. Fix $x \in (a, b]$. There is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $x - \frac{1}{N} \in [a, b]$. For $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $n >N$, there is $x_n \in [x - \frac{1}{N}, x]$ such that $\int_a^{x_n} f(t) \mathrm d t=0$. If not, $\int_a^y f(t) \mathrm d t \neq 0$ for all $y \in [x - \frac{1}{N}, x]$, leading to a contradiction because $\lambda ([x - \frac{1}{N}, x])>0$. Clearly, $x_n \to x$. By dominated convergence theorem, we get
$$
\int_a^x f(t) \mathrm d t = \lim_n \int_a^{x_n} f(t) \mathrm d t = 0.
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: There is not much to generalize since the function $x\mapsto \int^x_a f$ is continuous by virtue of $f$ being integrable.

Comment: @OliverDíaz You're right!