# Lebesgue differentiation theorem: how to obtain $\int_a^x F' \mathrm d \lambda = F(x)-F(a)$ in case $f$ is unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, proof-explanation, lebesgue-measure

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[a, b]$ and $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ [$\lambda$-integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space). We define $F:[a, b] \to \mathbb R$ by $F(x) := \int_a^x f \mathrm d \lambda$ for all $x \in [a, b]$. I'm reading a proof of Lebesgue differentiation theorem from [this](https://angyansheng.github.io/notes/measure-theory-xviii) note.

> **Theorem** $F$ is differentiable $\lambda$-a.e. and $F' = f$ $\lambda$-a.e.

The proof starts by considering a bounded non-negative $f$. Then the proof extends to unbounded non-negative $f$. A crucial step in the bootstrap is the identity
$$
\int_a^x F' \mathrm d \lambda = F(x)-F(a).
$$

This identity is obtained in the first case because $f$ is bounded by some constant $M>0$. Could you explain how it is obtained in the case $f$ is unbounded?

---

**Proof** Let's prove that $F$ is of bounded variation.  Let $a =x_1 \le x_2 \le \cdots \le x_n = b$. Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left| F (x_{i+1}) - F(x_{i}) \right| = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left|\int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}} f \mathrm d \lambda \right|
 \le \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}} |f| \mathrm d \lambda
= \|f\|_{L_1(\lambda)}.
$$

Hence $\operatorname{Var}_{[a, b]} F \leq \|f\|_{L_1(\lambda)}  <\infty$. It follows [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4609955/the-lambda-integrability-of-the-derivative-of-a-function-of-bounded-variation) $F$ is differentiable $\lambda$-a.e. and
$$
\int_a^x |F'| \mathrm d \lambda \leq \operatorname{Var}_{[a, x]} F \quad \forall x \in [a, b].
$$

1. We consider the case there is $M>0$ such that $0 \le f \le M$. Then $F$ is increasing. Hence $F' \ge 0$ and $\operatorname{Var}_{[a, x]} F = F(x)-F(a)$ for all $x \in [a, b]$. It follows that
   $$
   \int_a^x F' \mathrm d \lambda \leq F(x)-F(a) \quad \forall x \in [a, b].
   $$

Let $g:= M-f$. Then $0 \le g \le M$.  We define $G:[a, b] \to \mathbb R$ by $G(x) := \int_a^x g \mathrm d \lambda$ for $x \in [a, b]$. Then $G (x)= M(x-a)- F(x)$ for $x \in [a, b]$. As for $F$, we have $G$ is differentiable $\lambda$-a.e. and
$$
\int_a^x G' \mathrm d \lambda \le G(x)-G(a) \quad \forall x \in [a, b].
$$

First, it follows from $G' = M-F'$ $\lambda$-a.e that $\int_a^x G' \mathrm d \lambda = M(x-a) - \int_a^x F' \mathrm d \lambda$. Second, $G(x)-G(a) = M(x-a)- (F(x) - F(a))$. Then for $x \in [a, b]$,
$$
\begin{align}
M(x-a) - \int_a^x F' \mathrm d \lambda &\le M(x-a)- (F(x) - F(a)) \\
&\le M(x-a)- \int_a^x F' \mathrm d \lambda.
\end{align}
$$

It follows that
$$
\int_a^x F' \mathrm d \lambda = F(x)-F(a) =  \int_a^x f \mathrm d \lambda\quad \forall x \in [a, b].
$$

By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607832/if-int-ax-ft-mathrm-d-t-0-for-lambda-a-e-x-ina-b-then-f-0) lemma, $F' = f$ $\lambda$-a.e.

2. We consider the case $f \ge 0$. Let $f_n := f \wedge n$. Then $f_n \uparrow f$ everywhere. We define
   $$
   F_n :[a, b] \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto \int_a^x f_n \mathrm d \lambda.
   $$

By monotone convergence theorem, $F_n \uparrow F$ everywhere. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^x F' \mathrm d \lambda &\overset{\color{red}{???}}{=} F(x)-F(a) \\
&= \lim_n (F_n(x)-F_n(a)) \\
&= \lim_n  \int_a^x f_n \mathrm d \lambda \quad \text{by 1.}\\
&=  \int_a^x f \mathrm d \lambda \quad \text{by monotone convergence theorem}.
\end{align}
$$

It follows that $F' = f$ $\lambda$-a.e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a fix from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4610584/a-simple-proof-of-lebesgue-differentiation-theorem-for-dimension-1) thread.

---

- Second, we assume $f \ge 0$. We define
  $$
  f_n(x) :=
  \begin{cases}
  f(x) & \text{if } f(x) \le n, \\
  0 & \text {otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
  $$

Let $g_n := f - f_n$. Then $f = f_n + g_n$ and thus $F = F_n + G_n$ with
$$
F_n (x):=\int_a^x f_n \mathrm d \lambda
\quad \text{and} \quad
G_n (x):=\int_a^x g_n \mathrm d \lambda
\quad \forall x \in [a, b].
$$

Because $|f_n| \le n$, we get $F'_n = f_n$ $\lambda$-a.e. It follows from $g_n \ge 0$ that $G_n$ is increasing and thus $G'_n \ge 0$ $\lambda$-a.e. So
$$
F'=F_n'+G'_n \ge F'_n = f_n \quad \lambda \text{-a.e}.
$$

Taking the limit, we get $F' \ge f$ $\lambda$-a.e. and thus
$$
\int_a^x F' \mathrm d \lambda \ge \int_a^x f \mathrm d \lambda = F(x)-F(a) \quad \forall x \in [a, b].
$$

On the other hand, we [have](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4609955/the-lambda-integrability-of-the-derivative-of-a-function-of-bounded-variation)
$$
\int_a^x F' \mathrm d \lambda \le \operatorname{Var}_{[a, x]} F = F(x)- F(a) \quad \forall x \in [a, b].
$$

It follows that
$$
\int_a^x F' \mathrm d \lambda = F(x)-F(a) \quad \forall x \in [a, b].
$$